# Get "Cannot Post To Facebook" with iOS SDK when using test account

Tags: testing, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk, uiactivityviewcontroller, slcomposeviewcontroller

When attempting to post using a `Facebook` generated test account from the app using the `iOS 6` ,`UIActivityViewController` or `SLComposeViewController` I get the error popup message `"Cannot Post To Facebook - The post cannot be sent because the connection to Facebook failed"`. I see this both on an iPhone and the simulator.

The `iOS API` works fine with a real Facebook account.

The test account works fine when using the `Facebook iOS App` or the `web interface.`

Answer (score 1):

Facebook will not allow back to back posting of same content. But this case is not handled by SLComposeViewController. It will pass result as SLComposeViewControllerResultDone and through you an error message

> Cannot Post To Facebook - The post cannot be sent because the connection to Facebook failed.